# Library for asynchronous input from keyboard

Tags: c++, console

I have a console application that prints on standard output. I want to implement the following behaviour:

- Output is printed in a turns (2 seconds break after every turn)
- User may (it's optional for him) press a key to start printing other data
- When user don't click anything, output is just printed, nothing changes
- When user clicks a predefined key (he may be able to do that even during output is being printed) some function should be called

At first I thought about doing it in other thread (one thread for printing, one for waiting for input), but I suppose it's useless in this case, because it's impossible to wait for an input in a thread.

So I found two libraries that might be able to do that:

- Simple and Fast Multimedia Library (SFML): http://www.sfml-dev.org/index.php
- ncurses: http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html

I don't know either of them, so I am not sure which one I should learn to obtain a goal. Or maybe there is another, simpler solution?

OS: Unix

**EDIT:** g-makulik asked me to show, why it wasn't possible to write using threads insisting, that it is possible and indeed, it is, but I don't think this is how it should look like:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

void* print_message_function(void *doPrint) {
    bool* vDoPrint = (bool*) doPrint;
    while (*vDoPrint) {
        sleep(0.5);
        std::cout << "Thread 1" << std::endl;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void* keyPressed(void* doPrint) {
    bool* vDoPrint = (bool*) doPrint;
    while (*vDoPrint) {
        *vDoPrint = (char) getchar() == 'k' ? false : true;
        std::cout << "THIS ISN'T DISPLAYED UNLESS 'k' PRESSED.";
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
    int iret1, iret2;
    bool doPrint = true;
    iret2 = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, print_message_function,
            (void*) &doPrint);
    iret1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, keyPressed,
            (void*) &doPrint);

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

    std::cout << "Thread 1 returns: " << iret1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Thread 2 returns: " << iret2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think 'it's impossible to wait for an input in a thread'? You can of course wait for input either in your main thread and do output from another one or vice versa.

Comment: I cannot imagine how. One thread prints on a standard output. Correct, but how in other thread should I wait for the input? Should I simply use getchar() to the other thread? Console is busy printing, so how come, I'd be able to obtain this key pressed? I thought it's not so simple and I need to do get a monitor (Java name) and then try to write. This woudl remain synchronization as well.

Comment: Did you simply try that? Usually it won't be a problem to have one thread reading from (waiting at) `cin` while another one outputs to `cout`. A bit messy display for the user though if the input should be echoed. But as long it's just a reaction on `getchar` and a single key pressed in a menu like manner it shouldn't be a problem (even requiring sending the input using the enter key will work).

Comment: I am trying now. I tried before without faith of succeeding, so I gave up quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used ncurses before and while the following solution may not be the prettiest, it should work.

Ncurses allows you to put input into 'no-delay' mode. This makes `getch()`, which reads a character from input, non-blocking and it will immediately return ERR if user has not pressed anything.

You can wait for the standard input file descriptor to see if the input file descriptor is ready for reading. That is, `select()` or `epoll()` or whatever you want. If you have to do something every 2 seconds, you can just put that time to `select()` or `epoll()`. If you do get a keypress, you can then decide  whatever you want to do with it.

This solution needs no multithreading.

I have no knowledge of SFML so I don't know if it would make this any easier. Ncurses is a C-library which may or may not be convenient for a C++ application. If you have man pages installed, you probably can see documentation on any ncurses function directly (for example, `man getch`).

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to wait for keybord input from one thread while another one outputs to the same console. You just need to synchronize your threads (input/output) to obtain the functionality upon user inputs (e.g. using an event queue).

**EDIT:**
Using `select()` or `epoll()` with a timeout instead of separate threads might be a better choice on systems providing these system calls.

The ncurses lib will enable you to organize the console display in a window like manner (e.g. having separate panels to show the outputs and having kind of command (line) input). See [Midnight Commander](https://www.midnight-commander.org/) for an advanced sample what ncurses is able to do.

But as long you don't care about such separation for the echoed input in your application simple thread separation for input and output will work fine.

I can't tell anything about SMFL but this library seems to support windowing on a graphics level rather than a console.

Answer (score 0):

*SFML* is something I never heard about before. I can't say it's a bad choice but a pretty unpopular one, so it comes with a good likeliness that the users of your program will have to install it just for it. I wouldn't go that route.

*ncurses* is a pretty common and good solution but I think it's too complex for your case. ncurses comes in very handy when you are doing more complex text I/O, like drawing on screen, assembling windows, handling mouse etc. For such a simple application, I think it may be a bit overkill. On the other hand, if you want to catch very specific keypresses (e.g. arrow keys or other keys not resulting in text input) or handle mouse, then ncurses will help you.

Another popular and lightweight choice is *SDL* (with its SDL_input library). Unlike the previous solution, it's solely input-oriented. It will allow you to catch keystrokes, mouse clicks and possibly other input events with great detail, in non-blocking manner. However, you usually install libsdl as a whole and though it's tiny, I'm not sure if all users of your applications will appreciate that. Well, unless they use games which commonly use SDL.

And finally, you could implement such a simple thing yourself. If you care about *nix only (and not portability to systems like Windows), you can set `stdin` to non-blocking mode, and use repetitive non-blocking reads in the main loop to check for keypress. If your application does more waiting than actual processing between loop iterations, it may be better to use `select()` instead to handle both delaying and waiting for an input.

I would avoid introducing threads for that sole reason as they're inefficient and usually introduce more problems than they solve. You should never use threaded blocking I/O if non-blocking I/O is feasible.